# Adding iOS availability check to IBOutlet in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sign-in-with-apple

I'm adding Sign in with Apple to my app and am aware that it's only supported in iOS 13 and up while I still support back to iOS 11.

I want to add the button via Storyboards as that's what I'm using. When I add the button:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton *signInWithAppleButton;
```

I get the following warning:

[image]

as you would expect.

The fix-it adds an `API_AVAILABLE` macro just above my interface declaration, so it now looks like this:

```
API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))
@interface SignUpViewController ()

// .. bunch of IBOutlets
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton *signInWithAppleButton;

@end
```

My question is: is this correct? The app still runs perfectly fine on iOS 12, and I can just hide the button if it's running anything lower than iOS 13, but I just find it strange that the fix it is applied to the whole interface instead of just to the `IBOutlet` somehow.

Any info appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any answer about this thing? I am facing this issue on swift. and i also want to know how you handle this thing.